# Mount image of encrypted internal storage data partition from android P

Tags: backup, linux, encryption

When trying to upgrade to a newer rom, my system got a little messed up and I had to format my `/data` partition. I had made TitaniumBackup and twrp backups but they were on the encrypted data partition. When I flashed the new rom, this partition became all hashed folders and TWRP stopped asking me for the password. I took the time to do an `adb pull` of the `/dev/block/sda21` (which is the device that is mounted on `sdcard/`. How would I go about decrypting this on a linux device?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206762 https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145446

Comment: This solution works for Adoptable Storage, but the things could differ for `/data`. First of all the key isn't in `/data/misc/vold`, instead in crypto footer of `userdata` partition (usually last 16KB). Secondly the encryption algorithm may be different e.g. on Qualcomm devices `aes-xts` is used with `dm-req-crypt` while on others its `aes-cbc-essiv` with `dm-crypt` target. And the key is also bound to hardware.

Comment: in fact, they keys are gone. it is not possible to decrypt data (otherwise TWRP would do the job)

Comment: Yes, TWRP uses same code from `vold` which encrypts/decrypts `/data` on main Android OS.