# Is it possible to encrypt system partition with custom rom?

Tags: security, encryption, lineageos

I have galaxy s9 and i wanted to have lineageos rom.

So i unlocked bootloader and wiped stock firmware of galaxy s9.And then i installed lineageos 15.1 with twrp 3.2.3-0

Then i encrypted phone. I was thinking that by encryption device in adition to data patition, system partion also being encrypted. now i found that just data partition will encrypt and system partition will not encrypt.

so is there any way to protect system partition? in other words is there any way to encrypt system partition?

sorry  for poor english...

thanks

UPDATE :

sorry, It is possible that i am wrong or i don't understand what you mean but
I found from link below Boot verification occures when stock rom is installed and and bootloader is locked. but in my case bootloader is unlocked and therefore verifying not occures.

So i think there is no official way to check integrity of system partition and i should do another things like start a daemon in init.rc for verifying system partition or etc.

Is it true ?

And i should say i put an third-party app in system/app in twrp after mounting system partition and after restart it worked successfully.

[Android boot flow](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/boot-flow)

Comment: The purpose of encryption is to prevent "private" data from being accessed by unauthorised entities. Anything outside the data partition is public information so it is not a  sensible thing to do to encrypt the whole ROM. Know that encryption doesn't ensure that integrity of the data would remain protected.  If your primary purpose is to ensure integrity of your ROM, see https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot

Comment: ... and `/system`, `/vendor`, `/odm`, `/product` are read-only partitions protected by `dm-verity` - a very robust in-kernel framework - to avoid any changes to core OS.

Comment: Nearly duplicate of [If /system partition is never encrypted (even in "full-disk" encryption), how is it protected?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/206723/if-system-partition-is-never-encrypted-even-in-full-disk-encryption-how-is)

Comment: Boot verification (VB or AVB) is a long chain of trust; locked bootloader and `dm-verity` are part of it. You can't retain it fully on rooted devices but most of the times `dm-verity` can be retained to make sure some malware cannot harm your OS. It's also a requirement for OTA updates to work (usually on stock ROMs). Bind mounts (Magisk modules) can then be used to system-less-ly modify `/system`. However as you mentioned you have modified `/system` partition, `dm-verity` is for sure disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not encrypt system partition as there is no confidential data on the `/system`. There are only standard ROM files which are already available in public domain.

The encryption should only apply to the userdata partition `/data` or SD Card (if mounted as internal storage). Moreover `/system` is mounted as read-only. So, nothing can be tampered there.